# Trying to use old node versions for firebase compatibility

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to use an old version of node so that I can try to l[earn about firebase functions](https://www.toptal.com/firebase/role-based-firebase-authentication).

Currently, I'm getting an error that says:

> error functions@: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.
> Expected version "8". Got "12.18.1"

I tried adding the following to my package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8x"
  }
```

When I try that change, restart and test node -v, I'm still on version 12.

Does anyone know how to configure a react app to use node in a  way that is compatible with firebase functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a property to `engines` will not reinstall Node.js. You need to reinstall it with the official installer, pinning the package version for Linux, or using a Node version manager like n or nvm.

Answer (score -2):

Firebase Functions are compatible with node 10 AND UP.

Comment: But their problem is their own module.

Comment: no - it says an error because it wants to use v8.

Comment: I currently deploy over a dozen Cloud Functions, with the line
```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```
in my package.json (I do use a package that develops and deploys all my functions from a single deploy (export-functions, with slight modifications)).  Are you deploying to Google Cloud, or trying to somehow or another run them locally?

Comment: OR are you trying to implement the CloudFunctions *calls* in a node *client* SDK instead of node *admin* SDK?